# Should I use this simple two table system for messaging?

Tags: mysql, database, messaging

I'm looking to build an ultra-simple messaging system within a website. It can be one-to-one, or one-to-many, it doesn't matter. (Recipients will either be a `user_id` or `group_id`).

Looking at various solutions proposed, many advocate a three table system: `users`, `messages` & `message_recipients` which looks over complicated and possibly inefficient as you will inevitably end up a giant recordset in `messages` pretty quickly.

Obviously a `user` table is required, but for the messages I am considering just creating a unique table for each message thread based on associated `user_id`s. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user1_user2` (
`id` INT(10),
`originator` INT(10), // who initiates the message
`message` MEDIUMTEXT, // message body
`timestamp` VARCHAR(10)
);
```

No subject or thread name necessary. I would name the tables according to the associated ids in ascending order. (so no `user2_user1` table)

Obviously this approach will end up with a lot of tables eventually and which should probably be stored in a separate database. What are the drawbacks (if any) with this method as opposed to the standard three table method? Would this be more efficient in terms of retrieving data?

Comment: No!!!!!! Don't create tables on the fly -> DB designs need to be static. And BTW millions of records in a table are no problem to handle for a DB.

Comment: Why do designs need to be static?

Comment: Because it is a nightmare in maintenance and in coding to do otherwise. And there is absolutely no advantage in doing otherwise.

Comment: Agreeing @juergend's many exclamation points. Your database should grow in records, not in fields and tables. Long tables aren't a problem. It's what the RDBMS was built for. Lots of tables that are dynamically generated ARE a problem. It's NOT what the RDBMS was built for.

Comment: Thanks I've revised my approach to use a single table for all messages with columns for sender / recipients, so just `users` and `messages` tables required. Thanks for the heads-up!